# How to mount an iso image on Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, iso-image

I need to mount an ISO image on Linux. On Windows I use Daemon Tools, but how is this done on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop FILE.ISO /place_to_mount
```

Comment: And you have to be root.

Comment: This is correct. @Neuquino: Mark tur1ng's answer as accepted once you verify it works.

Comment: @dave if you mount it to a directory your user has access to, you do not need to be root for example "mkdir cdimage; mount -t iso9660 -o loop FILE.ISO cdimage" will work without needing to be root.

Comment: This is not working for me on Fedora 38 spin plasma. "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop10, missing codepage or helper program, or other error." Please advise?