# How to mount an ISO file without filename truncation on Linux?

Tags: linux, iso-image

When I use advice from https://superuser.com/a/119548/133421:

```
mount filename.iso /path/to/mountpoint
```

I get files, which seem to have names truncated at ~32 characters (or paths are truncated at ~48 characters). How do I mount an ISO file without this truncation?

Note: the same file was checked separately using builtin mounting in Windows 10's `explorer.exe`, with no issues.

Comment: Your kernel may be missing support for Joliet, a Microsoft extension to the ISO file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command `fuseiso`:

```
fuseiso filename.iso /path/to/mountpoint
```

It will mount the contents of iso file without this filename truncation issue. Unmounting is done as usual:

```
umount /path/to/mountpoint
```